# Fail with error 'Pancake: TRANSFER_FAILED'

Tags: pancakeswap

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x66f323c23d249c78da2b8f6f79faa1468bd98533618d7a655081075058e4d086
This deal was failed.
Status: Fail with error 'Pancake: TRANSFER_FAILED'
To: Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]
Please help me.

Comment: From the [VM trace](https://bscscan.com/vmtrace?txhash=0x66f323c23d249c78da2b8f6f79faa1468bd98533618d7a655081075058e4d086&type=gethtrace2), calling `transfer` on the [token HypeRise (HypeRise)](https://bscscan.com/address/0xb56642f6d0e5e3bd8ae1f1900a254c644c6246e8#code) run out of gas. Unfortunately I can't find where it is using that much gas.

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction is eating up all of your gas *limit* and failing. Instead of increasing your gas *price*, which is what you are not supposed to do, increase the limit to something like 500,000. You can keep the gas price at 5ish Gwei and have a reasonable confirmation time on BSC.